# HoloLens2 spatial mapping UNITY, I mapped a room and I want to get the coordinates of the corners

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapping, coordinates, augmented-reality, hololens

As I said in the title , what I'm looking for is a way to locate the corners of a room I mapped using spatial mapping on HoloLens 2. I'm trying to design a floor plane based on the the room I mapped and for that I need the coordinates of the corners. I was trying to find the data location for the created meshes and somehow locate the corners and their vertex and then start from there. But without any success. Also I tried to get the data from Windows Device Portal , but I have yet to understand how to use it properly. At the moment all I could do is get a 3d model of the space I mapped from 3D view.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg80S.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The device portal doesn't help in scenario, the map doesn't place markers for the corners, and there's no API exposed for the corners. A quick way to detect something in a room through an app (as opposed to a spatial map) is a [QR code](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-QRCode-Sample) in the corners (ceiling and floor).

Also, if what you want to create is a floor-like plane, then you can get the floor via [SurfaceType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.spatialawareness.spatialawarenesssurfacetypes?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0) and then create the plane based on its position.